# message not written in file, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, trace

Here is the code

```
class Program
{
    public static TraceSource TS = new TraceSource("myTraceSrc", SourceLevels.All);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TS.TraceInformation("Hello Trace from Main");
    }
}
```

here is the config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="myTraceSrc" switchName="switch1">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="myLocalListener" initializeData="c:\Test.Log" />
                <add name="consoleListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" name="consoleListener" traceOutputOptions="None" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
        <add name="switch1" value="all" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Message is displayed on the console but nothing goes in file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling [TraceSource.Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.flush.aspx)?

Comment: so is there anyway to have trace message written instantly rather calling Flush() every single time?

Comment: @imak: I think you want `<trace autoflush="true">` but to be honest I haven't used trace listeners myself.

Comment: @Jon: as far as i can see autoflush is available when you are using trace. In case of tracesource, i don't see this been available for  source, listener or switch. Not sure where to set this property

Comment: @imak: Right... I'm not sure either, I'm afraid :(

Comment: @Jon actually just added the line <trace autoflush="true" /> before <sources> and removed Flush() call and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the `TextWriterTraceListener` manually like it is described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788).